# Cannot upgrade Ubuntu 17.04 to 18.08

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, 17.04, repository

After trying to upgrade from 17.04 to 18.0 this message appears:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vlc/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-ubuntu-master-daily-zesty.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-ubuntu-master-daily-zesty.list:3
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does not have a Release file.   
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does not have a Release file.  
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-proposed Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I have a netbook eMachines E350, Intel Atom processor, and 2GB RAM memory. Is it necessary to download the 18.04 ISO image?

Comment: There was no 2018.August (18.08) release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 17.04's upgrade path was to 17.10, then to 18.04. Both 17.04 & 17.10 are now EOL, and after a release reaches EOL it's repositories get moved (*next comment will provide information on this*) which is why you get errors.  I'd suggest re-installing 18.04 (particularly Xubuntu 18.04 LTS or Lubuntu 18.04 LTS as they are lighter than gnome-based Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) but you could upgrade to 17.10 then 18.04 LTS but it'd take a lot longer & more effort.

Comment: I would suggest sticking to LTS or Long-Term-Support releases if you don't want to upgrade every 9 months as required by non-LTS releases.  Ubuntu 17.04 reached EOL back on 13-January-2018.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove reported error repository from Ubuntu **Software & updates -> Other Software** and try it to upgrade again.